# Behavior of fscanf when format doesn't match file contents

Tags: c, file-io, c99, scanf

If the contents of a file do not match the format string passed to `fscanf`, what happens on the next call to `fscanf`?

Suppose a file contains the following two lines:

```
9000 pig dog
4 5 2
```

A program tries to parse the opened file (`fp`) as such:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
int x = 1, y = 1, z = 1;

fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

I suspect that `a` would now hold `9000` while `b` and `c` continue to hold the value `1` -- but what happens to `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Does the **C99** standard guarantee that `x`, `y`, and `z` will hold the values `4`, `5`, and `2` respectively -- or is the file stream's position indicator guaranteed to be left unmodified after a failed parse, causing `x` to hold the value `9000` while `y` and `z` hold on to the value `1`?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)?

Comment: @nightcracker Yes, in particular section **7.19.6.2** paragraph 2 confuses me since it doesn't mention what happens when the format doesn't match the string, but rather when format doesn't match the arguments. Which paragraph refers to the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Section 7.19.6.2*
>
> 4) The **`fscanf`** function executes each directive of the format in turn. If a directive fails, as
>   detailed below, the function returns. Failures are described as input failures (due to the
>   occurrence of an encoding error or the unavailability of input characters), or matching
>   failures (due to inappropriate input).
>
> 5) A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>   ﬁrst non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>   be read.
>
> 9) An input item is read from the stream, unless the speciﬁcation includes an `n` speciﬁer. An
>   input item is deﬁned as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any speciﬁed ﬁeld width and which is, or is a preﬁx of, a matching input sequence. The ﬁrst character, if any, after the input item remains unread.

So `a` will be 9000 and `b` and `c` continue to be 1. The stream is read upto (but not including) `pig`, so the first `%d` of the second call immediately fails, causing `x`, `y` and `z` to remain 1.

Comment: In paragraph 4 it states that an *input failures* are `due to the occurrence of an encoding error or the unavailability of input characters`. Regarding the latter case of an input failure, does this mean that a format string of `"%d %d %d"` against the file content of `10 42` would result in an *input failure* rather than undefined behavior, due to "unavailability of input characters?"

Comment: @VilhelmGray I don't understand how it would be undefined behaviour - it's clearly defined from the paragraphs I quoted (the function returns). Consider this: how would anyone ever be able to safely use `scanf` without risking undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing from my handy copy of "Standard C" by Plauger and Brodie, fscanf() returns on...

- end of format string
- EOF on file
- conversion failure

On conversation failure, it's not stated clearly, but I assume the failing character is pushed back on the stream.  So your "p" character would be on the stream.

Note that the return value of fscanf() is the # of input items matched. So success for you would be a return of 3 each time.  I'd expect returns of 1 and 0 in your example.