# How to read file and validate input?

Tags: c, arrays, file

Today I'm learning about File in C and come up with a problem

First I created a text file as below:

```
5 1 5 2 4 -3
```

The first element is the array size and I wrote a function to read all positive value into an integer array using this code:

```
void readFileToArray(char *fname, int *a, int *pn) {
    int number;
    int quantity;
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &quantity);
    while (*pn < quantity) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
        if (number >= 0) {
            a[*pn] = number;
            (*pn)++;
        }
        else 
            quantity--;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And it successfully read 1 5 2 4 into the array

Next I changed the text file into this

```
5 1a 5 2 4 -3
```

Thanks to Tutorialspoint, I figured out how to eliminate 1a and read 5, 2, 4 into the array with this code

```
void readFileToArray(char *fname, int *a, int *pn) {
    int number, test;
    char space;
    int quantity;
    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &quantity);
    while (*pn < quantity) {
        fpurge(stdin);
        test = fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &number, &space);
        if (test != 2 || space != ' ')
            quantity--;
        else {
            a[*pn] = number;
            (*pn)++;
        }
    }   
    fclose(fp);
}
```

However with the text file

```
5 1a a5 2 4 -3
```

The previous code block cannot read the file into array. When I tried to debug, I noticed the below code line

```
test = fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &number, &space);
```

It read a5 and returned value 0, which is correct. At this moment:

```
number = 1
space = a //because it cannot read a5 into the format %d%c
```

However, at the next loop run, number and space still held the value 1 and a until loop end. Program exit with no value read into the array

Can anyone explain why and suggest me a solution?

P/s: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Would suggest you to read how to tokenize a string based on space `' '`character. Then analyse individual token to check if they are integers  and if they are integers then convert the tokens into integer and then insert them into array.

Comment: For starters, you should always check the value returned by `fscanf()`.  It's pretty hard to validate the data from that call if you don't even know if it worked.

Comment: Using `fscanf` will limit your program to work in 1 specified manner. Instead I will recommend using `fgetc`, it will read a file character by character and then you can use `ASCII` values to determine wheater you need that character or not.

Comment: Read the _line_ with `fgets()` and then parse it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the fscanf() function call is looking for a pattern in the input stream (ie: the text in your file), which should start with a decimal integer. since "a5" does not start with an integer or a sign ('-'), a matching failure occurs. When the matching failure occurs, the character "a" is pushed back onto the stream, and the fscanf function returns. During the successive loops the same thing happens, since the input stream is from a file, and will not change.

A very similar issue was discussed in the following stack overflow thread:
[Behavior of fscanf when format doesn't match file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816766/behavior-of-fscanf-when-format-doesnt-match-file-contents)

Since you mentioned that you are learning C, I would suggest you look at the various code examples in the "The C Programming Language by K&R" Book. I remember that Some of the examples use getchar() to parse input from stdin. You can use the same methods but with fgetc (as mentioned earlier by Sma). I am sure you will enjoy reading the book (And learn the language at the same time!!)